# Exiting the current chain of middleware without throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I'm looking for a way to exit a chain of middleware without calling `next()`.

Here's an example below. This works but I have to check for `req.filter` every time to ensure it's set to false. Does express have any way of exiting the current chain of middleware (moving to the next route) without throwing an error (`next(new Error("will exit and move to error handler")`)?

What I really want is a `nextRoute()` handler that will exit the stack of middleware for this route and move to the next.

```
function queryExists(query){
  return function(req, res, next){
    if(!dotty.exists(req, "query."+query)) req.filter = true
    return next()
  }
}

app.get("/", queryExists("foo"), queryExists("bar"), function(req, res, next){
  if(req.filter) return next()
  return res.send(req.query.foo + " | " + req.query.bar)
})

app.get("/", function(req, res, next){
  return res.send("hi")
})
```

I'd love some framework or library that solves this problem in any standard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you need to skip the rest of the middleware from a router
>   middleware stack, call next('route') to pass on the control to the
>   next route. Note: next('route') will work only in middleware loaded
>   using app.VERB() or router.VERB().

```
return next('route')
```